# How to handle events on different element in java script for responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery

While developing responsive web design i am using ZingTouch as a javascript library for handling mobile based events such as **swipe,pinch,pan,rotate etc** 
i am handling design using media queries but the problem is when deciding the behaviour of web page if a certain element lets say have a '**tap'** event which is similar to **on click** event in desktop will get trigger twice and if they have same properties it will over ride for eg :

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
   //For mobiles and tablet,will not work as on click will over ride it
   
    var menu = document.getElementById("list");
    var menuRegion = new ZingTouch.Region(menu);
    menuRegion.bind(menu,'tap',function(){
    $("#list li").css("color","blue");
    });
    
    //For desktop

    $("#list li").on('click',function(){
      $("#list li").css("color","orange");
      
      //alert("hello") different properties will be called in chain and both will execute i.e defined in tap as well as for click.
    });
    
    //Some different event on same element with different properties will again over ride it 
    
    var menu1 = document.getElementById("main");
    var menuRegion1 = new ZingTouch.Region(menu1);
     menuRegion1.bind(menu1,'swipe',function(){ debugger;
    $("#list li").css("color","red");
    });
    
});
```

```css
#list
{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100px;
}
#main
{
  border:1px solid orange;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zingtouch/1.0.5/zingtouch.min.js"> </script>
<body id="main">
<ul id="list">
<li> option 1</li> 
<li> option 2</li>  
<li> option 2</li>  
</ul>
 </body>
```

To see result for **swipe event** just swipe inside yellow box by holding left mouse button and moving cursor left to right upto 6 to 8 times to see the effect.

The problem is though all this are in one file that's why this is happening but if i am using media queries to detect resolution for design do i have to do similar for JS too and then load JS file based on screen resolution or there can be an alternative to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution but yet effective to tackle this problem there can be some alternative i guess here is the sample code

```
$(document).ready()
{
  function someName()
  {
    //the R.H.S width should be the one define in media query for laptops and desktop
    if($(window).width() > 1281) 
    {
      //Function logic goes here
    }
  }
  $("elementname").on('click',function()) //can be any event click,mouseover etc
  {
    if($(window).width() > 1281) //check width
    {
      //Function logic goes here 
    }
  })
  $("elementname").on('tap',function())
  {

  })
}
```

Thus by checking width for every event the script will only get executed once for that device and not for mobile or tablet and both logic can be kept inside file